# Past Perfect and Past Simple (looking for the correct answers)

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

I have one sentence:

```
We were late for the theater because ___ .
```

Possible variants:

1. she had left the tickets at home
2. we had gotten lost while driving
3. he had wanted to watch an action flick

Perhaps it sounds awkward to natie, but why the last two answers are incorrect (according to the resource I've taken this example from)?

Comment: Do you have the resource from which you took this example? It would help us explain why they say it's wrong. Especially since you had also mentioned it :D.

Comment: Meanwhile, number two sounds OK to me. Number three sounds fine grammatically, but it is a bit of a jump in logic to go from "wanting to watch an action flick (so we had an argument about it) so we were late."

Comment: Also, I would have said, "late for the movie" and "late to the theater" if it's a movie theater. I would use "for the theater" only if it for were a live show. But I know this is just my American English rearing its ugly head. I'm pretty sure other English variants use "for the theater" for movie theaters.

Comment: They are all equally viable from the point of view of tense. In colloquial speech, the simple past is likely to be used instead of the past perfect.  ,,,because she forgot the tickets...because we got lost....because he wanted to finish watching an action flick...  The word **because** does most of the temporal heavy  lifting in context: causes precede their consequences, and so we don't need the past perfect to make sense of the statement.  By contrast: *We were late for the movie. We had gotten lost on the way.*

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang, Coursera materials

Comment: @TRomano, it's become clearer (using Past Perfect with "because" we make a kind of "semantic overload") and I understand it now. Thank you.

Comment: "Had gotten" is sometimes used, but it's better to simply say "got".

Comment: The more i speak to natives the more I notice that they simplify everything. **We were late for the theater because she left the tickets at home**, **because we got lost while driving**, **because he wanted to watch an action flick** all sound fine without the Past Perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to me, the correct use of [tense](https://www.examweb.in/use-of-tense-for-ssc-banking-railways-exams-146) in the following sentences is -
We were late for the theater because we had/got lost while driving. ( Here **got lost** may mean **had lost**. Therefore **had gotten lost** looks awkward here/superfluous here).
2. We were late for the theater because he wanted to watch an action flick.(
 Past Indefinite is OK here. No need of Past Perfect. **Had wanted** shows that he had the old desire to see the the action flick but we didn't pay attention.